# Trouble using PHPThumb class under namespace

Tags: php, interface, namespaces

I am trying to use PHPThumb class. Something strange is going on. I have included three files in my script. I've made sure that these files are correctly included.

```
<?php
include('PHPThumb-master/src/PHPThumb/PHPThumb.php');
include('PHPThumb-master/src/PHPThumb/GD.php');
include('PHPThumb-master/src/PHPThumb/PluginInterface.php');
```

Each file has a class define under a `namespace PHPThumb;` Like:

```
<?php
namespace PHPThumb;
class GD extends PHPThumb { ...
```

and so on other files too..

But when I try to make an object `$gd = new GD()`, it says:

```
Fatal error: Class 'GD' not found ...
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I learned about namespace in PHP here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.basics.php. So this solved my problem.